# System of particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, energy-conservation, coulombs-law

We have two charged particles $Q$ of mass $m$. One is placed on the ground (particle 1) and the other at a distance H above the ground (particle 2). The particle 1 has an initial velocity $v_1$ in the direction of particle 2, instead the other is free to fall (it has not an initial velocity). The problem requires to find the smallest distance $d_{min}$ between the two particles.

I came up with this equation for total energy:

$$E_{tot}=k_0\frac{Q^2}{d}+2mgH_{c.m}+\frac12mV_1^2+\frac12m V_2^2+\frac12 (2m)V_{c.m}^2$$
    (c.m is the centre of mass)

$$E_{0}=k_0\frac{Q^2}{H}+2mgH_{c.m}+\frac12mV_1^2+\frac12(2m)V_{c.m}^2$$
$$E_{final}=k_0\frac{Q^2}{d_{min}}+2mgH_{c.m-min}$$
But I do not know how to go ahead. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How can the first particle move ? You're talking about falling, so you consider that the gravitationnal interaction between the two particles is negligible in front of the attractiion of Earth ?

Comment: I negleted the gravitational energy between the two particles.

Comment: Note that d, $V_1$ and $V_2$ are related. Furthermore think about what is happening physically and from that deduce the velocities $V_1$ and $V_2$ at the moment of smallest distance.

Comment: They should be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Here, due to the symetry of the problem, this is a 1D situation: both particles will stay on the vertical axis they were initially. Thus, when their distance will be the smallest, their relative speed will be null.

Let's call $H_i$, $V_i$ the position and speed of particle $i$. Then, we got

$$\begin{cases}
m\frac{\textrm{d}^2H_1}{\textrm{d}t^2} = -mg + \frac{k_0 Q^2}{(H_2-H_1)^2} \\
m\frac{\textrm{d}^2H_2}{\textrm{d}t^2} = -mg - \frac{k_0 Q^2}{(H_2-H_1)^2} 
\end{cases}
$$

so with $D = H_2 - H_1$:

$$
\frac{\textrm{d}^2D}{\textrm{d}t^2} = \frac{k_0Q^2}{mD^2}
$$

so after multiplying by $\frac{\textrm{d}D}{\textrm{d}t}$:

$$ \frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}t}\frac{1}{2}\dot{D}^2 =k_0Q^2\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}t}\frac{-1}{mD} $$

so $$\frac{1}{2}\dot{D}_{min}^2 - \frac{1}{2}\dot{D}(0)^2 = k_0Q^2(\frac{1}{mD(0)} - \frac{1}{mD_{min}})$$

However, when $d=d_{min}$, $\dot{D} = \dot{D}_{min} = 0$, $\dot{D}(0) = -v_1$ and $D(0) = H$ so finally

$$D_{min} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{H} + \frac{mv_1^2}{2k_0Q^2}}$$

Comment: I think that in the final equation there should be the mass m (I am not completely sure).

Comment: user154508 You were right, I edited my answer

Comment: For the sake of quickly checking units, I'd multiply that fraction by $\frac{H}{H}$  and pull the $H$ in front of the fraction.

Comment: I have a doubt is the correct equation $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{H}+\frac{mv_{1}^2}{4k_{0}Q^2}}